# sql query record selection

Tags: sql

I have data like below:

```
DHAddressID Address     CreatedDate
12814       1 Santa AVE 2021-01-21 01:22:42.000
16003       1 Santa AVE 2021-01-21 01:22:43.000

I am looking to pick only the last record with max CreateDate

select DHAddressID, Address, max(CreatedDate)
from table
group by DHAddressID, Address
```

The above return two records, but I need one as given below

```
 16003      1 Santa AVE 2021-01-21 01:22:43.000
```

any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical way uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by DHAddressID order by CreatedDate desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks but still returning more than 1 record, I need only one record. If I exclude DHAddressID then get the required record but I want the DHAddressID and the max CreatedDate

Comment: Thank you, got it, you saved my day.